# Filter data in CouchDB as IN in MySQL

Tags: couchdb

I am wondering if i could filter data in Couchdb similar with IN in MySQL. For example the map function is :

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.idWord, [doc.idTwitterData, doc.tf*doc.idf]);
}
```

I want to select only documents that have idWord with values 1 or 5 for example. I tried to set startkey=1 and endkey=5 but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. All you need to query is `?keys=[1,5]`. This will fetch all the records with the idWord equal to 1 or 5. You might want to encode the **[ ]**

As an addition: you use the parameters startkey and endkey if you are doing a ranged query. Here is a good explanation how a ranged query works.